# Blocking sms and calls iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I did some research and it seems that a lot of people are claiming you can't block calls on your app but I recently found an app on the store called Whitelist [White List Manager](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whitelist-manager-filter-phone/id575473157?mt=8) which did exactly what I wanted on my app.

Are they using a private API? If so how did they get this approved?

Comment: Have you spend $1.99, and check whether it is working or not. Plz read review, there are something you should know.

Comment: Yeah that app does not actually work, its a fake app that just makes people use the built in Do Not Disturb feature of iOS.

Comment: one comment : Waste of money! 
by cubewebsolutions
Doesn't work at all on iPhone 5 with latest iOS. No whitelist shows in settings and you can't add to the whitelist either. Apple needs to remove this fake app.